# C++ Mastermind - one scenario not working

Tags: c++

Could someone give me a hand in trying to figure out why this doesn't work for the following scenario?

Server code:  *1441*

My guess:  *1114*

Output:  *Your Guess:  1114
1 black hits & 3 white hits.*

This should instead be 1 black and 2 white, right?

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

typedef enum {RED,GREEN,BLUE,YELLOW,ORANGE} color;

std::vector<color> GetInputAsColorMap(std::string input)
{
    std::vector<color> theCode;

    std::istringstream iss;
    iss.str (input);

    int theNumber;
    iss >> theNumber;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
    {
        theCode.push_back(static_cast<color>(theNumber % 10));
        theNumber /= 10;
    }
    std::reverse(theCode.begin(), theCode.end());
    return theCode;
}

int StartMasterMind(std::istream& userInput) 
{
    std::cout << "Welcome to ... M A S T E R M I N D.\n";

    // there are 6 colors
    std::vector<color> the_colors(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        the_colors[i] = color(i);

    std::vector<color> ServerCodeColorVector; 
    std::string strValue;
    std::getline(userInput, strValue);

    if (strValue == "random" || strValue == "Random")
    {
        // initialize random seed and shuffle all_colors
        srand(time(NULL));
        std::random_shuffle(the_colors.begin(), the_colors.end());

        // fill real_code with the four first colors
        std::vector<color>::iterator it = the_colors.begin();
        // ServerCodeColorVector.insert(it,4);
    }
    else
    {
        ServerCodeColorVector = GetInputAsColorMap(strValue);
    }



    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
        std::vector<color> current_try(4);
        int black_hits = 0, white_hits = 0;
        std::vector<int> correctColorIndex;
        std::vector<int> correctColor;

        bool exclude[4] = {false};

        std::cout << "Your Guess:  " << std::flush;
        std::cin >> strValue;
        current_try = GetInputAsColorMap(strValue);

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (color(current_try[j]) == ServerCodeColorVector[j]) {
                black_hits++;
                exclude[j] = true;
                correctColorIndex.push_back(j);
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
            {
                if (std::find(correctColorIndex.begin(), correctColorIndex.end(), j) != correctColorIndex.end())
                    break;

                if (color(current_try[j]) == ServerCodeColorVector[k] &&
                    !exclude[j])
                {
                        correctColor.push_back(j);
                        ++white_hits;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }       

        std::cout << black_hits << " black hits & " << white_hits
                    << " white hits.\n";

        if (black_hits == 4) {
            std::cout << "you won!\n";
            return 0;
        }
    }   

    std::cout << "The real code was ";

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        std::cout << ServerCodeColorVector[i] << ' ';

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Gimme: " << std::flush;
    StartMasterMind(std::cin);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not excluding when you are finding a white hit. Also, the exclusion is done on the wrong index:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            if (std::find(correctColorIndex.begin(), correctColorIndex.end(), j) != correctColorIndex.end())
                break;

            if (color(current_try[j]) == ServerCodeColorVector[k] &&
                !exclude[k])                     // *** This should be k, and not j
            {
                    correctColor.push_back(j);
                    ++white_hits;
                    exclude[k] = true;           // *** Add this line
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see you haven't accepted my answer. If the answer did not resolve your problem, I'd like to help further - just post whatever new information you've gathered from trying my solution.

Comment: Sorry, it was 3am when I posted and I went directly to bed :) -- I'll give this a shot when I get some time, or after work!

Comment: Your solution was close - it ended up being that I needed to check `!exclude[k]` and add `exclude[k] = true;`  --- thanks!

Comment: Yes, nice catch. I fixed my answer to reflect this, in case anyone else finds his way here.